# Ionic 2 Date doesn't work correctly in emulator

Tags: android, date, timezone, ionic2

I need to get date time from device, but when i use new Date(),output is bad. In browser it's work correctly.

```
var now = new Date();
console.log(now); // in browser works
Dialogs.alert(now); // in emulator doesn't
```

In emulator have set time automatic. Problem is that emulator have 11:00 while new Date prints 9:00. Is there any problem with emulator timezone or something?

Comment: What about using [moment timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) just in case to prevent that from happening?

Comment: i look at it but it working just like Date `moment().seconds(30) === new Date().setSeconds(30);`